# What are the Negative Effects of Not Closing a InputStreamReader

Tags: java, io

I'm revising some code for a Java program written by another programmer and I'm wondering what would be the difference in wrapping an `InputStreamReader`in `BufferedReader` vs making a `InputStreamReader` object then making a new `BuffererReader` object on top of that. For example, what is the benefit of this

```
FileInputStream localFileInputStream = null;
localFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(someFile);
InputStreamReader localInputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(localFileInputStream);
BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(localInputStreamReader);
// Do some file processing 
localFileInputStream.close();
localInputStreamReader.close();
localBufferedReader.close();
```

vs

```
FileInputStream localFileInputStream = null;
localFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(someFile);
BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(localFileInputStream));
// Do some file processing 
localFileInputStream.close();
localBufferedReader.close();
```

In the first block of code I call `localInputStreamReader.close();` but in the second block I don't (don't know how I would). Would this make any difference?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmzuRXLzqKk

Comment: `What are the Negative Effects of Not Closing a InputStreamReader` - running out of file descriptors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Java docs ([BufferedReader)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html):

> close
>
> public void throws IOException
>
> Description copied from class: Reader
>
> Closes the stream and releases any > system resources associated with
> it. Once the stream has been closed, further read(), ready(), mark(),
> reset(), or skip() invocations will throw an IOException. Closing a
> previously closed stream has no effect.
>
> Specified by: close in
> interface Closeable Specified by: close in interface AutoCloseable
>
> Specified by: close in class Reader
>
> Throws: IOException - If an I/O
> error occurs

Calling close() on the BufferedReader closes the underlying stream by default implementation, since it's specified in the superclass Reader. So both of your code snippets actually do the same. Sure if there would be no such specification, or you would use your own writer and forget to close your given stream, it will have some effect. For example not closing a FileInputStream makes the underlying File inaccessible or at least unwritable.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in the second code snippet the call to localFileInputStream.close(); is also unnecessary since the call to localBufferedReader.close() would also close the FileInputStream?

Comment: Yes since close() on BufferedReader would cascade down to the underlying InputStreamReader, which is also inheriting from the Reader class, and that would closes its underlying FileInputStream. But as it's also stated in the docs, if the underlying streams are already closed, nothing happens. So you can't be safe enough :)

Answer (score 1):

It is worth mentioning that

```
BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(someFile)));
// Do some file processing 
localBufferedReader.close();
```

is sufficient.
with Java 7 and up, you use try-with-resources to not forget closing it:

```
try(BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(someFile)))) {
  // Do some file processing 
}
```

Note that the API of *java.io.Closeable* (which all your Readers and InputStreams implement) says:

> Closes this stream and releases any system resources associated with it.

So the spec requires compliant implementations to actually delegate the close call to all wrapped resources.